# Applying CSS through jQuery to several selectors simultaneously

Tags: jquery, css

is it possible to assign CSS styles through jQ to several selectors in one statement like it can be done through pure CSS?

```
var foo = $('#thisEl');
var boo = $('#thatEl');

[foo and boo].css({
...CSS here
});
```

Comment: Yes. Basically any selector you can use in CSS you can also use as a jQuery selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You you can use [multiple selectors](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

```
$('#thisEl, #thatEl').css({
...CSS here
});
```

or if you have references to jQuery wrapper object only then use [.add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/) to create a new combined jQuery wrapper

```
var foo = $('#thisEl');
var boo = $('#thatEl');

foo.add(boo).css({
...CSS here
});
```

Comment: btw, would `foo.add(boo).add(goo).css({...` work if you want 3 or more elements?